# Google Vision API detects labels for only public images on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vision

I am storing images on Google Cloud Storage and using Google Vision APIs to detect labels of those images. I use the same account and credentials for both purposes.
I am using the sample program given at:
 'https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/vision/cloud-client/detect/detect.py'

I can successfully detect labels for the local images and images on internet which are publicly accessible.
When I use the following with a image stored in a bucket on my GCP storage, the program does not detect any labels unless I mark the data (image) as public.

e.g.

When it is private:

```
# ./detect.py labels-uri 
'https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/mybucket/o/Penguins.jpg?
generation=1510548912343529&alt=media'
Labels:
```

When I mark it as 'public':

```
# ./detect.py labels-uri 
'https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/mybucket/o/Penguins.jpg?
generation=1510548912343529&alt=media'
Labels:
penguin
bird
king penguin
flightless bird
beak
organism
```

I was expecting, since I am using the same credentials for the vision and storage API access, it should even work on my private images.

Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When referencing a Cloud Storage object, use the URI pattern `gs://bucket_name/object_name`.

Try `./detect.py labels-uri gs://mybucket/Penguins.jpg`

Cloud Vision supports both Cloud Storage objects as well as any arbitrary URL. However, when you reference a URL, Cloud Vision does not forward your credentials there, unlike when you reference a Cloud Storage object directly. Here you're specifying a URL that would attempt to download a Cloud Storage object anonymously, which is not what you want. (Note however that Cloud Vision does not support specifying a specific version of a GCS object -- for more, see https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate).

Comment: Cool !! That works pretty well. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Hm, regardless of the gs:// or http:// image URI, Google cloud vision still expects a public image, it does not use the credentials used to invoke the cloud vision API to access the image. You need to send OAuth authentication information along with your request for a user or service account which has permission to read the GCS object, per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125608/how-to-enable-google-vision-api-to-access-google-cloud-storage-bucket-within-sam

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with a non-public GS bucket:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path-to-your-creds.json"
```

Python3:

```
import json

import google.auth
import requests
from google.auth.transport import requests as grequests
from google.cloud import storage

URL = "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1p4beta1/files:asyncBatchAnnotate"


credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"])
credentials.refresh(grequests.Request())
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + credentials.token, "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"}

request_json = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "inputConfig": {
                "gcsSource": {
                    "uri": "gs://your-input-bucket/test.pdf"
                },
                "mimeType": "application/pdf"
            },
            "features": [
                {
                    "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"
                }
            ],
            "outputConfig": {
                "gcsDestination": {
                    "uri": "gs://your-output-bucket/json"
                },
                "batchSize": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}

response = requests.post(URL, json=request_json, headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```