# Enable Cloud Vision API to access a file on Cloud Storage

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth, google-cloud-vision

i have already seen there are some [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42125844/6752358) but none of them actually provide a full answer.
Since I cannot comment in that thread, i am opening a new one.

How do I address [Brandon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81491/brandon-yarbrough)'s comment below?

> "...
>   In order to use the Cloud Vision API with a non-public GCS object,
>   you'll need to send OAuth authentication information along with your
>   request for a user or service account which has permission to read the
>   GCS object."?

I have the json file the system gave me as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/common/auth) when I created the service account.
I am trying to run the api from a python script.

It is not clear how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to use the [Vision API Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries) for python to perform the call. You can install it on your machine (ideally in a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)) by running the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-vision
```

Next, You'll need to set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the file path of the JSON file that contains your service account key. For example, on a Linux machine you'd do it like this:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/service-account-file.json"
```

Finally, you'll just have to call the Vision API client's method you desire (for example here the `label_detection` method) like so:

```
def detect_labels():
    """Detects labels in the file located in Google Cloud Storage."""
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    image = types.Image()
    image.source.image_uri = "gs://bucket_name/path_to_image_object"

    response = client.label_detection(image=image)
    labels = response.label_annotations
    print('Labels:')

    for label in labels:
        print(label.description)
```

By initialyzing the client with no parameter, the library will automatically look for the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable you've previously set and run on behalf of this service account. If you granted it permissions to access the file, it'll run successfully.